# makeset operation not preserve ordering?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

The following command does not produce a consistent ordering of items:

```
KubePodInventory
| where ClusterName == "mycluster"
| distinct Computer
| order by Computer asc
| summarize makeset(Computer)
```

But upon reading the documentation ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/advanced-aggregations#generating-lists-and-sets)) it states the following:

> Like makelist, makeset also works with ordered data and will generate
>   the arrays based on the order of the rows that are passed into it.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wroing?

Comment: If the answer works, please help mark it as an answer. It would help others. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/24135#issuecomment-460185491) @MohitVerma mentioned, makeset() should not support ordering, and they are planning to correct the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/advanced-aggregations#generating-lists-and-sets) : **Like makelist, makeset also works with ordered data and will generate the arrays based on the order of the rows that are passed into it.**

You can use makelist() as a workaround, which does support ordering as per my testing.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this answer for the similar type of operation.

[How to order item in Makeset?](https://github.com/microsoftdocs/azure-docs/issues/24135)

Below code worked for me-

```js
requests | summarize makeset(client_City) by client_City | distinct client_City | order by client_City asc
```

[image]

You can follow this thread for the code snippet , marked the answer for closing this thread.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/24135#issuecomment-460185491

```js
requests | summarize makeset(client_City) by client_City | distinct client_City | order by client_City asc | summarize makelist(client_City)
```